# How to add field customizable by the theme editor to your theme?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm adapting a theme for my use, and it currently doesn't have a field for a banner in the header and I would like to add one.

But rather than hardcoding it into the theme, I would like to be able to select the header image with the theme customizer, where can I learn to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theme Customization API** on Wordpress Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I couldn't come up with the term to google it and I was just getting results for plugins